# The determinant without calculating.

Tags: matrices, determinant

The determinants of two matrices are equal and it can be known without computing.

How do you know that?

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        9 & 2 & 8 & 1 & 2\\
        8 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 12\\
        6 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 8\\
        8 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 12\\
        2 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 9\\
        \end{pmatrix}
 $$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        9 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 2\\
        2 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 3\\
        6 & 16& 3 & 4 & 8\\
        2 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 3\\
        2 & 4 & 7 & 12 & 9\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The two matrices are related by row and column operations. To obtain the second from the first, divide rows 2 and 4 by 4, and multiply columns 2 and 4 by 4.